# Clone / Copy state is returning empty state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am having an issue using **lodash's cloneDeep** to clone the user object passed in from the store. When I attempt to render the data in the template `{{ user }}` shows the data retrieved from the store and `{{ userCopy }}` shows the empty store. I am not sure why this is happening, I am new to Vue.

**store/staff.js**

```
import StaffService from '~/services/StaffService.js'
export const state = () => ({
  user: {
    offers: '',
    legal: ''
  }
})
export const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
}

export const actions = {

  fetchUser({ commit, getters }, id) {
    const user = getters.getUserById(id)

    if (user) {
      commit('SET_USER', user)
    } else {
      StaffService.getUser(id)
        .then((response) => {
          commit('SET_USER', response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('There was an error:', error.response)
        })
    }
  },

}

export const getters = {
  getUserById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.staff.find((user) => user.id === id)
  }
}
```

**pages/settings/_id.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ user }} // will display the whole object 
    {{ userCopy }} // will only display empty store object
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash'

data() {
  return {
    userCopy: _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state.staff.user)
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapState({ user: (state) => state.staff.user })
},
created() {
   this.$store.dispatch('staff/fetchUser', this.$route.params.id)
},
</script>
```

Comment: Have you imported `mapState` into your component? Like this, for example: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper

Comment: Only like the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that a Vue instance's `data` is initialized before `state` becomes available. While `computed` props are populated/updated as their data source change.

If the component doesn't need to change the value of `user` during runtime, I'd suggest turning it into a `computed` property.

If your component does change the value during runtime (such as when it's `v-model`'d to an input), there are two approaches you can do.

**Method 1: Using `mounted` hook**

This is done by placing `user` in `data` property and then assigning a value when the instance is [mounted](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle#mounting-(dom-insertion)), like so:

```js
mounted () {
  this.$data.userCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state.staff.user)
}
```

**Method 2: Using `computed` with `getter` and `setter` functions.**

Normally, you shouldn't change a `computed` value. But it can be done using a setter function. With this, when Vue detects an attempt to change a `computed` prop it will execute `set()` with the old and new values as arguments. This function would change the value at its source, allowing `get()`'s returned value to reflect this. For example:

```js
computed: {
  userCopy: {
    get () {
      return _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state.staff.user)
    },
    set (newValue) {
      this.$store.commit('updateStaff', newValue) // Replace this line with your equivalent state mutator.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to implement Method 1. ``user`` data is returned through mapState and I have added an empty ``userCopy`` in data. But an empty store is still displayed when ``{{userCopy}}`` is called

Comment: I am still unable to fix this issue